# Nginx reverse proxy working on localhost but not on K8S

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running a reverse proxy on my local docker and it works.

Once I deploy the docker image to K8S it gives a 404.

Is it an issue from the 3rd party site? 
How do I debug it?

```
location /cs/outsession/products/ {
    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass 'https://www.google.com.hk/';
}
```

Comment: What's on the dest server? right now you are sending a connection through reverse proxy_pass, with the url : "/". Do you want the destServer to read "/cs/outsession/products" (then delete that last / you have on the proxy pass)? do you want to pass a $host header as your host? Also, do you have the logs or config of the destiny server?

Comment: It can preform what I want on localhost, everything works fine. What I am trying to do is build a link to return content from our CMS. But once I deploy the image to K8S it returns a different result.